# Is there a paper/manuscript explaining the theory behind AnyDice?

Tags: dice, anydice

I am using the [AnyDice](http://anydice.com/) website to calculate probabilities on any number of dice with any arbitrary number of sides. May I please have a link to a formal discussion of this very elegant subject?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not within the scope of RPGs.

Answer (score 9):

There have been hundreds of books written on this topic, and there's even a whole branch of mathematics called Probability that studies this in detail.

This following link discusses the theorems behind it very clearly, written in formal mathematical language:
http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Dice.html

Answer (score 2):

[This essay](http://www.darkshire.net/jhkim/rpg/systemdesign/torben_rpg_dice.html) specifically looks at how dice are used in RPGs and how to calculate probabilities for them. It might be more helpful than some other resources because it is written with a focus on RPGs.

[This playlist on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLC58778F28211FA19) has some good video tutorials on probability theory.

If you want to really dive into probability, you could also download [this 520 page textbook](http://www.dartmouth.edu/~chance/teaching_aids/books_articles/probability_book/amsbook.mac.pdf) from [Dartmouth](http://www.dartmouth.edu/~chance/teaching_aids/books_articles/probability_book/book.html).